# Как поменять размер bullet в li?

Tags: css

```
    li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: small;
    }

li:before {

  content: '\2022';
    font-size: 38px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    }
}
```

пытаюсь так , но меняется и ширина между строк из за `font-size` можно ли просто увеличить (сделать жирным) bullet  по другому , так как мне этот оступ не нужен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать позиционирование:

```css
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: small;
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: '\2022';
  font-size: 38px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: -13px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>один</li>
  <li>два</li>
  <li>три</li>
  <li>четыре</li>
  <li>пять</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: спасибо. просто вытащил